# How to parse a Postgresql JDBC url to get hostname, port and db_name

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

What is the best way to parse a Postgresql JDBC URL to get the hostname, port and database name.

This is a specific case of this question: [How to parse a JDBC url to get hostname,port etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9287052/how-to-parse-a-jdbc-url-to-get-hostname-port-etc)

Answer (score 3):

A possibility is to use the [Postgresql JDBC driver](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/7b7d2a9140dba1733cdd4bb720912621578ba846/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/Driver.java#L552) to parse the URL.
This works, of course, only if it is a Postgresql URL.

If the provided URL contains no fail-over host the following can be done:

```
Properties props = org.postgresql.Driver.parseURL("jdbc:postgresql:myDatabase", null);

String host   = props.getProperty(PGProperty.PG_HOST.getName());
int    port   = Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty(PGProperty.PG_PORT.getName()));
String dbName = props.getProperty(PGProperty.PG_DBNAME.getName());
```

The above call returns the following properties: `{PGDBNAME=myDatabase, PGPORT=5432, PGHOST=localhost}`

If the URL contains fail-over hosts the host property and port property contain multiple, comma-separated values. For example the call

```
Properties props = org.postgresql.Driver.parseURL("jdbc:postgresql://host1:5434,host2:5433/database", null);
```

will return the following properties: `{PGDBNAME=database, PGPORT=5434,5433, PGHOST=host1,host2}`

Comment: I'm curious, what will this do with multi-host URLs (see https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html under _Connection Fail-over_ near the end)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I did not know about fail-over hosts. I enhanced the answer accordingly.